# Linked Server and Constraints SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Does anyone know if you can drop a constraint on a table via a linked server in SQL 2005

Answer (score 1):

[Can you have a Foreign Key onto a View of a Linked Server table in SQLServer 2k5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442587/can-you-have-a-foreign-key-onto-a-view-of-a-linked-server-table-in-sqlserver-2k5)

I would say you can not.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but you have to use some dynamic SQL trickery to make it happen.

```
declare @cmd VARCHAR(4000)
SET @cmd = 'Use YourDatabase
ALTER TABLE YourTable
DROP CONSTRAINT YourConstraint'

exec YourServer.master.dbo.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Very late but this is genious, Finally found what I needed